# Equivalence of categories, exercise from Category theory in contexts

Tags: category-theory

I'm having huge trouble with the exercise 3.1.xii from the book Category theory in contexts:

[image: problem]

I.e. prove that the category $\int \text{Cone(-,F)}$ is equivalent to $\int \text{Cone(-,FE)}$, where $\text{Cone(-,G)}$ sends an object $c \in C$ to set of cones over $G$ with apex $c$ and $\int(-)$ denotes category of elements.

Assume $E':J \rightarrow I$ is an equivalence such that $EE'$, $E'E$ are naturally isomorphic to identities.

First I have defined a functor $H:\int \text{Cone(-,F)}\rightarrow\int \text{Cone(-,FE)}$ that takes natural transformation $(\lambda _{j}:c\rightarrow Fj)$ to transformation $(\lambda_{Ei}:c\rightarrow FEi)$. Then I defined composite functor $K:\int \text{Cone(-,FE)} \rightarrow \int \text{Cone(-,F)}$ that first takes natural transformation $\mu = (\mu_{i}:c \rightarrow FEi)$ to $\mu E' = (\mu_{E'j}:c\rightarrow FEE'j)$ and then (assuming $\beta:EE' \Rightarrow 1_{J}$ is natural iso) to $(\beta_{j}\mu_{E'j}:c\rightarrow Fj)$.

According to my computations $KH, HK$ are **identities** (so the categories are **isomorphic**) - hence my assumption that my "proof" is wrong.

Could someone point out why is my approach wrong and suggest better one?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, isomorphic categories are equivalent...

Comment: @ArnaudD. To be fair, when you do an equivalence-respecting calculation, getting the result that two categories are *isomorphic* is mildly surprising, so lacking a reason to think some aspect of the calculation is subtly strictifying the situation, "I did something wrong" is a reasonable suspicion.

Comment: As ArnaudD said above isomorphisms are equivalences. So if your proofs were true than you just simply had proved your claim. Nevertheless if you do not provide the calculations or at least the sketches of you proof no one can validate your proofs. You can just said I proven this and then this without giving the specifics.